# Is there a word to express "the rain of sakura petals"?

Tags: words, culture

I think it's a good question given the season.

I was watching the petals of cherry flowers falling down in the typical "pink shower" after the full bloom and wondered: is there a word that expresses exactly this phenomenon of cherry petals "raining down"?
After all it is such a typical "Japanese scene" that I would be surprised otherwise. However, I asked a Japanese person who didn't know (and if such word exists I figured it would be so common everyone would answer immediately).

Ps I know 桜が舞う、桜の舞。 I was curious about a single word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but we take it as snow rather than rain.

**[桜吹雪【さくらふぶき】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/87191/meaning/m0u/)**

> 桜の花びらが風に乱れ散るようすを吹雪にたとえていう語。
>   *a word describing cherry petals whirling down in the wind by analogy with snowstorm*

---

[image]

Comment: After the "sakurafubuki", roads are covered with the petals of cherry flowers. Alas, the petals usually become miserable by the rainfall soon after. But I know the helpful scene for the fallen petals. You could see a beautiful carpet made by the fallen petals of cherry flowers on the surface of the pond around the Imperial Palace. You can share the beauty with me at the URL site written below: rekishi-roman.jp/page-3-1.html

Comment: Damn. I really wanted it to be ザーザークラ.